# Sending email content as an attachment using PHP and SendGrid cURL

Tags: php, email, sendgrid

I'm building a WordPress based delivery site. In every transaction, I'm sending an email with HTML content using SendGrid & cURL. The email will also be faxed to some users (using RingCentral - another third party service). The issues is that, the context should also be sent as an attachment.

If I use a static file (test.txt), everything works fine.

I need to send the content (`"$email_heada {$_message[$eid]} $email_foota"`) as the attachment. There is a possibility of concurrency issues (multiple users send email at the same time, etc)

Below is my current code:

```
$fileName = 'test.txt';
$filePath = dirname(__FILE__);

$params = array(
    'api_user'  => $sendgridusername,
    'api_key'   => $sendgridpassword,
    'to'        => $email,
    'subject'   => $mySubject,
    'html'      => "$email_heada {$_message[$eid]} $email_foota",
    'text'      => "$email_heada {$_message[$eid]} $email_foota",
    'from'      => $settings_general->pear_user,
    'files['.$fileName.']' => '@'.$filePath.'/'.$fileName
);

$request =  $sendgridurl.'api/mail.send.json';

// Generate curl request
$session = curl_init($request);
// Tell curl to use HTTP POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
// Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
// Tell PHP not to use SSLv3 (instead opting for TLS)
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// obtain response
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);
```

Any suggestions? Thanks before

Answer (score 1):

you need to load the file

```
$fileName = 'test.txt';

$file = file_get_contents('./'.$fileName, true);

$params = array(
    'api_user'  => $sendgridusername,
    'api_key'   => $sendgridpassword,
    'to'        => $email,
    'subject'   => $mySubject,
    'html'      => "$email_heada {$_message[$eid]} $email_foota",
    'text'      => "$email_heada {$_message[$eid]} $email_foota",
    'from'      => $settings_general->pear_user,
    'files['.$fileName.']' => '@'.$file.'/'.$fileName
);
```